# VisualSVN, SVN Locks and Datasets

Tags: svn, dataset, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

We are using Visual SVN and VS2010, we have a data project with several Datasets in it. To avoid having to try and merge the XSD files we have set them to require a lock so only one person can edit at a time.

The only problem is, when someone expands the TableAdapters and DataTables in the designer it asks for a lock, I have excluded the layout files (xss,xsc) from the "requires-lock" property, but is still asks for the lock.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sending a bug report to support@visualsvn.com with a reproduction script, clarification of what project template is affected and with Visual Studio 2010 info details is the best way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a bug. Most likely the designer asks to edit a file with svn:needs-lock and that's why VisualSVN requires you to lock the file.

Please provide us with detailed report on this problem at: http://www.visualsvn.com/support/feedback/
Note that detailed reproduction script will help us to investigate and solve this problem quickly.